# How to set resultsLimit of jQuery token input plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-tokeninput

How to set limit to 10 that should `token input plugin` suggest ? I want to set limit to 10 so `jquery token input plugin` can suggest only 10 search.

I have tried `resultsLimit: 10` in initialization function still it is not working.

Any solution ?

Comment: can you post the code you tried?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/):

> **resultsLimit**
>   The maximum number of results shown in the drop down. Use null to show all the matching results. 
>   default: null

So you therefore you just need to set this property when you initialise the plugin:

```
$("#myInput").tokenInput('/path-to-data/', {
    resultsLimit: 10
});
```

Comment: I have already tried this but it is not working dont know why ?

Comment: Works for me. We need to use the url (webapi or webmethod) to get data.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and got it to work by modifying the token input JS file. Add the following pieces of code.

```
Line 46 : resultsLimit: null,

Line 680 : in populate_dropdown function
//Setting search limit
if (results.length > settings.resultsLimit) {
results = results.slice(0, settings.resultsLimit);
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/issues/542